# Can an application distributed using Mac Apple Store auto-update its database?

Tags: macos, appstore-approval, mac-app-store

The [Mac Apple Store Approval Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/mac/resources/approval/guidelines.html) states that:

`2.21 Apps may not use update mechanisms outside of the App Store`

Now, if you develop an application that is something like a dictionary and you want to update the data often (maybe daily), the Mac App Store update mechanism is useless because it would require Apple approval.

The question is if such an application, that is apple to update it's database by itself, will be accepted by Apple.

I am not sending this question to Apple because, at this moment I do not have an OS X developer account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that guideline is referring to updates of the App itself. I think if you alert users that the app will be downloading a new database, you should be fine.